# How can i use the visual shader on the Enviroment Sky Godot

Tags: c#, godot, godot-shader-language

how can i use the visual shader in the enviroment sky godot 3.4 any idea?
I dont have nothing else to put..
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Post-processing

You might be trying to make some post-processing effect. in that case, you have these options:

- Use a `ViewportContainer` and `Viewport` combo, then you can use a Canvas Shader on it. See [Custom post-processing](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/viewports/custom_postprocessing.html).
- Use geometry that covers the view, and use a Spatial Shader on it. See [Advanced post-processing](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shading/advanced_postprocessing.html).
- There are, of course, some post-processing options available on `Environment`. See [Environment and post-processing](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/3d/environment_and_post_processing.html).

---

**Color Correction**

If you set `adjustment_enabled` to true, you can set a texture on `adjustment_color_correction`. This means you can set a `ViewportTexture` as described at the end. *Godot is expecting a gradient.*

---

### Custom Background

If you want to make a custom background or sky. Look at the property `background_mode` in the `Environment` object under "Background". There are only two cases that are useful for us:

- `PanoramaSky`: If you set the `background_mode` to "Sky" or "Color+Sky", you can set a new `PanoramaSky`, which has a property `panorama` that takes a texture. *Godot expects an [equirectangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) texture*. And thus, you can set a `ViewportTexture` as described at the end.
- `Canvas`: If you set the `backgroud_mode` to Canvas, you can figure some Canvas Layers to be in the background. And, of course, you can set a Canvas Layer with `CanvasItem`s that have Canvas Shaders. *Remember that you can get the current `Viewport` with `get_viewport` and from it, the current 3D camera with `get_camera`. Thus, you can use the orientation of the current 3D camera to update the contents of the Canvas Layer.*

---

### Appendix: ViewportTexture

If you have a texture property that you want to make dynamically, you can create a `Viewport` and then set a `ViewportTexture` to the property, referencing the `Viewport`.

That allows you to use shaders (or whatever you want) to create the texture you want. Because the texture will be whatever scene is rendered in the `Viewport`.

There is just one caveat: you cannot do this on a resource saved independently of a scene. Thus, to set any of the textures of the `Environment`, you will need to save it as part of the scene (which also means not using the default environment). So add a `WorldEnviroment` node to the scene, give it an `Environment` and make sure it has `resource_local_to_scene` set to true.

Comment: I tried using viewport but the dimensions confuse me

Comment: @Rubénramirez It is an equirectangular projection. Imagine the image has the left and right edges glued into a cylinder, and then the cylinder is pinched down into a sphere ([something like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Ic5ZIf74Ls)). You can think of the horizontal coordinate as azimuth, and the vertical as altitud. Search for [equirectangular skybox](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=equirectangular+skybox&t=opera&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images) for reference. *In fact, try a few.*